# Image does not appear in Jar executed with double click

Tags: java, eclipse, image, jar, icons

After extracting a Runnable Jar in Eclipse Version 2020-12 (4.18.0), when I run it with double click the image is not displayed:

[image]

However, when using java -jar meujar.java the image is displayed:

[image]

Image addition code:

```
JLabel lblImage = new JLabel();
lblImage.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
lblImage.setBounds(275, 30, 225, 225);
lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("logo.png"));
```

The addition of the label to the frame was made by windows builder, following part of the code:

```
.addComponent(lblImage, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 225, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
.addComponent(lblImage, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
```

Comment: From the looks of it `logo.png` is an external file, which should be stored relative to the "working" directory.  Instead, you should consider using an "embedded resource" instead, which will allow the code to load the image from within it's own bundle context (from the Jar file in most cases)

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files so you can't use the file name version of the ImageIcon constructor to access the image in the jar.

Comment: If I can't use the file name in ImageIcon, what should I use? @greg-449

Comment: See the answers in the duplicate